# Given three sets $A,B$ and $C$. Does $A\cap C = B\cap C$ imply $A=B$? (Prove if this is true or give a counter example)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given three sets $A,B$ and $C$. Does $A\cap C = B\cap C$ imply $A=B$? (Prove if this is true or give a counter example)

Im not entirely sure if I am right, however, I came up with this. 
Please correct me if I am wrong and help me. Thanks in advance.

Given $A\cap C = B\cap C$ , $A$ is not equal to $B$.
Counter example:- $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$ and $C = \emptyset$

$A\cap C = \emptyset$. Similarly, $B\cap C = \emptyset$.
Thus $A\cap C=B\cap C$. However, as we can see, they aren't equal.

Is this correct? Please help
Thank you.

Comment: Your example is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct. In terms of propositional logic, it's equivalent to taking different propositions $a,\,b$ with $c$ a contradiction to verify $a\land c=b\land c$ (both sides are contradictions) doesn't imply $a=b$.